# 301 path redirect in web.config

Tags: xml, apache, azure, url, web-config

I am trying to get a web redirect to work for my wordpress site, but nothing happens for the redirect url.

The site is wordpress and has an existing web.config file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**I want the url to redirect FROM /path/to/old TO /path/to/new and have added the following after the first rule:**

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^path/to/new" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http:/www.site.com/path/to/new" redirectType="Found"/>
</rule>
```

So the full code looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule>
               <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="^path/to/new" />
                 <action type="Redirect" url="http:/www.site.com/path/to/new" redirectType="Found"/>
               </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
         </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I am new to web.config, but have used .htaccess before. A bit clueless here why it is not working – nothing happens on the site when I enter the URL that should be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the rules a prioritized by their order, meaning your wildcard rule processes all the requests before the specific rule and then the requests don't match the pattern.

Try placing the **Redirect** rule before the **WordPress** rule and remove the **stopProcessing** attribute.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to the IIS documentation at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/

it looks like this can be as simple as putting

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http:/www.site.com/path/to/new" />
```

to the root of `<system.webServer>` perhaps even before the rewrite mod.  Can you give that a try and let us know if that works for you.

Comment: please note, you might have to install the HTTP Redirection module on the server's IIS if not already installed, check the setup section on the link provided.